# Parsing numbers based on dynamically specified types in Scala

Tags: python, parsing, scala

Coming from a Python background, I'm used to having types available as objects at runtime. Having that, combined with the fact that at least in the case of `int` and `float` these type objects also happen to be callables that act as parsers (e.g. `int("234") == 234`, like Scala's `"234".toInt == 234`), I can come up with a solution to parse, say, a matrix of either integers or floating point numbers from a text file. The only thing I have to do is configure a parameter:

```
 ITEM_TYPE = int  # or float
```

and I'm good to go:

```
 with open('matrix.dat') as f:
   matrix_data_raw = parse_raw_matrix(f.read())
 matrix = [map(ITEM_TYPE, row) for row in matrix]
```

changing the value of `ITEM_TYPE` to `float` immediately gives me a `list` of `list` of `float`s at runtime (there's no static typing but the contents of `matrix` are still strongly typed to be either `list[list[int]]` or `list[list[float]]`).

In Scala, I would expect the static type of `matrix` to be e.g. either `Matrix[Int]` or `Matrix[Double]` (from, say, a more general `type Matrix[T: Numeric] = Vector[Vector[T]]`). However, being a relative beginner with Scala, I'm a bit lost as to how to achieve this. There's no obvious/easy way to just switch the value of a parameter from `classOf[Int]` to `classOf[Double]`—even if I did that and dynamically chose the parser function accordingly (which would straightforward), how would I go about changing the runtime type of `matrix` from, say, `Matrix[Int]` to `Matrix[Double]`? And what would I have to declare the static type of `matrix` to be—`Matrix[Numeric]`?

Before you judge the naiveté of the question, I'll admit that I'm aware that the Scala'esque solution probably requires a somewhat different approach, but I just liked the idea of starting my thoughts off of the (IMO rather elegant) Python solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is worth pointing out that the runtime type of your matrix is always Matrix[Object] - running on the JVM, generic types are erased at runtime.

That said, you can still specify the runtime type of the elements in your matrix. I think you'd have to do this with a function though. I'll use lists to illustrate this:

```
val int: (String => Number) = _.toInt
val float: (String => Number) = _.toFloat
```

You'd have to define any of these that you'd potentially use at runtime. That done, usage is simple:

```
val NUM_TYPE: (String => Number) = int // or whichever you choose

...

val list = List("1", "2", "3") map (NUM_TYPE)
```

This will always give you back a List[Number], but it will be populated with (in this case) Ints.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it doesn't cover the aspect of dynamically choosing the type to parse.

Comment: Updated, hopefully better illustrates what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Define this whereever makes sense, possibly as an abstract method in a trait
// with suitable concrete implementations that you can mix in to the class doing
// the matrix work, or with the body determined based on config data, etc.:
def itemType: String => Number = _.toInt // or _.toDouble or whatever

// Set up your read:
val matrixDataRaw = parseRawMatrix(f.read()) // Matrix[String] at this point
val matrix = matrixDataRaw.map(itemType)
```

You might, however, be better off passing itemType into your parsing function and converting the text snippets before putting them in the matrix class (which currently needs a map method defined on it to do the transform).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this.  The best thing I can suggest would be if you know you're either going to be getting ints or floats, do both of them.

```
trait Matrix[+A]

def parseRawData[A : Numeric](fp: io.Source, parseNum: String => A): Matrix[A]...

def manipulateRawData[A : Numeric](fp: io.Source): Matrix[A] = {
  val mat = parseRawData
  val numeric = implicitly[Numeric[A]]
  ...
}

if (ints) {
  manipulateRawData[Int](fp, _.toInt)
}
else if (doubles) {
  manipulateRawData[Double](fp, _.toDouble)
}
```

You can see that you end up with a Matrix[AnyVal] at the end (be careful about your types), but it will do the right thing intermediately.

Comment: My concern is the kind of duplication found at the end of the snippet—ideally I could do `manipulateRawData[???](fp, if (ints) _.toInt else _.toDouble)`, or, actually even dynamically choose the parsing function should I want to choose a completely new type altogether (e.g. complex numbers or symbols).